# Cannot pass data using PubSub.publish in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Cannot pass data using the pubsub component from the Product component to Cartlist component.i need to pass the list object to the Cart component.The product component renders a list of products.So each item has to be passed as props to the Cart Component when clicked.

```
import React from 'react';
import PubSub from 'pubsub-js';
import Productlist from '../component/productlist';
import Addtocart from '../component/addtocart';

var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');
var Product = createReactClass({
    addtocart:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        PubSub.publish('add-cart','helloworld')
    },

    render:function(){
        var list = this.props.dataname;
        return(
            <div className="card hoverable">
                <div className="card-image">
                    <img src={list.image} alt={list.name} className='shop-img' />
                </div>
                <div className="card-content">
                    <span className="card-title blue-text text-darken-2">{list.price}&nbsp;{list.currency}</span>
                    <p>{list.name}</p>
                </div>
                <Addtocart onClick={() => this.addtocart(list)} />
            </div>
        )
    }

})

export default Product;
```

Cartlist Component

```
import React from 'react';
import PubSub from 'pubsub-js';

var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');
var Cartlist = createReactClass({

    componentWillMount:function(data){
     PubSub.subscribe('add-cart',function(data){
          console.log(data);
      });
    },

    // addtocart:function(data){
    //     console.log(data);
    // },

    render:function(){
        var list = this.props.dataname;
        return(
            <div className="card hoverable">
            </div>
        )
    }

})

export default Product;
```

Demo link demonstrating the issue http://codesandbox.io/s/x7p856zmjp

Comment: Pubsub works in React 16  - I'm using it myself. Can you please create a working demo project in github or similar? We cannot assist if we cannot see the problem. It could be an issue with your bundling/compiling pipeline.

Comment: @damanptyltd i have the demo within https://codesandbox.io/s/x7p856zmjp

Comment: I need to pass the data when clicked to the Cartlist component through pubsub.publish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sandbox, I can see the problem and have fixed all your issues in the following working demo https://codesandbox.io/s/2nv93ro4n

1. You had used class instead of className in some places in addtocart.js
2. You had 'MY TOPIC' as the subscription, but a different publish name
3. You were never creating the cart component.

I'm going to assume 1 and 2 were mistakes made in the demo you created, not in your original application. I believe 3 is the true culprit. If you never create a component anywhere, the mount events will never fire nor will any of its other code. I have added it to your app.js (though you can decide the business logic and location of the cart yourself). I wonder if you should combine the addtocart and cart components into one, and have addToCart as a function of the cart?