# How to communicate between two independent components in react js 16.x version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to communicate between two independent components in react js of version 16.x.I have used PubSub library to pass data but it didn't work.Is there a way to make this library working in the latest version of react js or any other method to pass data to a different component.Here is my code [Cannot pass data using PubSub.publish in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121755/cannot-pass-data-using-pubsub-publish-in-react-js)

Comment: You use events through flux or redux

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service in JavaScript code

```
// services.js



class Shared {
   sharedData;
}

const  serviceName = new Shared();

export default serviceName;
```

// in you component

```
import serviceName from './services.js';

// set data
serviceName.sharedData = {somdata:[]};


// get data
code = serviceName.sharedData;
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to use redux.
In React, you can pass data (state) from parent to child. You can also pass callbacks from parent to child, so that an event in the child will trigger an event in the parent that will modify the data (state) of the parent.